# Foreign Key's value in a table populated with random data MYSQL

Tags: mysql, random, foreign-keys

I want to populate with random data the tables of my MYSQL database, in order to test its performance.

I got a problem: if I have a table X with fields A,B,C and C is a foreign key that references D in another table Y, how can I do?

I'm using a tool to generate random data for A and B, but I really don't know how can I combine that with random values of C (taken from D values in the Y table).

Comment: I can't add manually a value of D in each C field because I'm adding something like 10.000 rows :(

Comment: @njk: Then one won't witness realistic performance for data modification queries.

Answer (score 1):

Your tool could implement the following pseudocode:

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
  $d = randomvalue();
  execute("INSERT INTO Y(D) VALUES ($d)");

  while ($j=0; $j<20; $j++) {
    $a = randomvalue(), $b = randomvalue();
    execute("INSERT INTO X(A, B, C) VALUES ($a, $b, $d)");
  }
}
```